# SASS with custom template selector

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I am using a templating system where I need to set the CSS selector to #%id%. However, no matter how I try to trick SASS into using that selector I cannot get it to work. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can make this work?

I am always getting this error.

`Invalid CSS after "#": expected id name, was "%id%"`

Update:

Here is what I have tried...

```
@mixin thing($id) {
  ##{$id} {
    color:red;
  }
}
@include thing(unquote('%id%'));
```

...and...

```
$id:'%id%';
##{unquote($id)} {
  color:red;
}
```

...lastly...

```
#%id% {
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: updated with a few ways that I have tried to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this. `#%id%` is an invalid CSS selector, and Sass can't parse it.

Comment: Is there a reason there is no way to escape a string in SASS?

Comment: In most circumstances, using `#{}` will allow you to use arbitrary strings even when that would result in invalid CSS. However, Sass needs to be able to fully parse selectors in particular in order to support features like `@extend` and the `&` parent selector.

Comment: #%id% is the selector of the parent div of all the CSS defined. Is there a way that I can simply inject #%id% at the parent to all the styles defined? Could this be done through a Compass function? Does SASS support any plugin architecture that would allow me to write this myself in ruby?

Comment: I have been reading through all the SASS docs and I don't see a currently supported way of extending SASS in this way. I think what I will have to do is simply build a post-processor for my own reasons that will add the `%id%` selector _after_ SASS has done its job.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
@mixin thing($selector) {
  #{$selector} {
    color: red;
  }
}

@include thing("#someId");
```

Comment: This is similar to one of the solutions that I tried. Sadly, the issue was that % is not allowed in CSS selectors and it was causing SASS to throw and error. This is a very fringe use-case for SASS and I am not surprised that it did not work. My post-processing solution seems to be working perfectly though.